# HP Pavilion g7 - Screen contrast adjusting itself

Tags: windows-7, hp-pavilion, contrast

I can't really think of any reason as to why this would happen, but lately my laptop has been acting a bit odd. It is an HP Pavilion g7 2017cl.

This has happened now twice - the screen will slowly (over a period of about 10 seconds) fade into a much higher contrast that's really annoying to look at. The only explanation is that I hibernate my computer a lot instead of shutting down/restarting.

It seems to be fixed after a restart, but obviously I'd like to fix the main problem instead of just making it go away for a week.

Comment: Can you set yourself the contrast using keyboard buttons or graphic driver's application?

Answer (score 1):

**Partial answer**

This is a copy and paste from the HP support forum on this issue:

```
Was your video card built by AMD/ATI?

If so, the Vari-Bright feature must be on. To fix this go to:
1. AMD Vision Engine Control Center (or AMD Catalyst Control Center)
2. Power
3. PowerPlay
4. Uncheck the "Enable Vari-Bright" option.

and that will fix your problem.
```

[Source](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Display-and-Video-e-g-Windows-8/My-screen-keeps-dimming-on-an-HP-Pavilion-g-notebook-with/m-p/1500691#M45640)

---